# Select words before and after the comma by SQL selecting

Tags: sql, split

I have a location column with the format sth like "Los angeles,LA,US". How to select only "Los angeles,US" in SQL selecting? 
 In other words, how to remove the word between two commas?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, fix the title.  `'Lost angles'` is two words, not one, so the title is misleading.

Comment: Also, the Southland's actual city is `Los Angeles`, not `Lost Angeles`.  Though, your version of the name might be a great title for a TV drama airing on Hulu.

Comment: Use `split_part()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, as long as you are certain that there will always be two commas ...

You can get Los Angeles by

```
SELECT LEFT( 'Los angeles,LA,US', Charindex(',','Los angeles,LA,US') - 1 )
```

You can use substring as well if you do not like Left.

For the second one, you will have to use substrings and two charindexes  to skip the first comma:

```
SELECT Substring( 
    'Los angeles,LA,US', 
    1+ CHARINDEX ( ',',  'Los angeles,LA,US',  1+ Charindex( ',','Los angeles,LA,US')  )
    ,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your data is in the field 'City' in the table 'Locations':

`select CONCAT(LEFT(City, CHARINDEX(',',City)), RIGHT(City, CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(City))-1)) 
as ShortName from Locations;`